# Attaching light shed to an insulated wall?

Tags: shed, design

I would like to build a light* storage shed between two buildings with insulated walls (A, B) which should not be touched by any further construction works (drilling etc.).

- Please help me to find a good solution.

In limited space conditions as shown below, two partial solutions come to my mind:

**Option 1: Shed with all walls**

[image]

Problem:

- narrow sections between building walls and shed are not maintainable and will host insect, collect old leaves etc.

**Option 2: Partially walled shed**

[image]

Problem:

- I do not know how to flexibly connect shed walls with building walls in places marked with purple "?". There must remain space for dilatation of the shed structure. Maybe something similar to idea of [swimming noodles](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=swimming+noodles) making the contact of the walls will work?

*) as an opposite of heavy non-removable structure which requires local government approvals

Comment: Option 2 will have an effect on the Elecrical Code.  With those 3 buildings now attached they are one building for purposes of panels, multiple circuits, ground rods, disconnects, etc.

Comment: To Downvoter – why do you think this question was of low quality so I can improve it...

Comment: probably because it's too broad of a question, try focusing it down

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but, since it doesn't have an accepted answer...

Build shed option #1, but turn it 90° so it's 2.2m wide by 3.7m deep.

You will have the exact same amount of storage space, however, there will be more room for maintenance (mowing, leaf raking, etc) between the shed and the 2 adjacent buildings.

Answer (score 0):

Screw 2x4 into the corners because they will have woodstuds. Now u can hang your sheed walls on it in solution 2. This assumes you have wood buildings. Well if u have stonewall's you can do the same with concrete ankers and long screws. All that would be on to of ur insolation. Swimming noodles is for going  swimming

Comment: The OP asked for methods not needing "drilling"...